# Feedback from tapping UIBUtton in code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have buttons and a selector for the buttons, the code looks like this:

```
[cell.secondColumnButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whichButtonDidMasterPressed:)    
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.secondColumnButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreResponsiveButtons:)    
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Right now I have this in the "moreResponsive" selector:

```
-(void)moreResponsiveButtons:(UIButton*)sender{
   NSLog(@"responsiveButton");
   [sender setAlpha:0.5];
   [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
}
```

The button is invisible  when it's in a normal state, but I want to change the state to have feedback when the user taps it.

So the question is two-fold, which forControlEvents should I use?

And what code should I put in the selector?

The button i quite big, 250 x 175 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How user knows where to tap a button if it is hidden?

Try using UIControlEventTouchUpInside like this:

```
[cell.secondColumnButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreResponsiveButtons:)    
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**EDIT**

```
[sender setHidden:NO];
[sender setTitle:@"Hey you pressed this button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can set title on button before touch and it won't be visible cos button is hidden. After touch you just set hidden to NO and voila. Button is shown with text inside.

Comment: The buttons are just an overlay to more things underneath, but if I should put the more responsive code in the whichButtonDidMasterPressed selector, which code is recommended I should put there?

Comment: I don't understand you quite well. But if you want to show that button you should set property setHidden:NO or setAplha:1.0. I you set alpha to 1.0 but button was hidden before, you will not see it.

Comment: The button should only be visible when the user taps it, and then it should only give feedback to the user like saying "Hey you pressed this button". That's my question, let me worry about the button in it's normal state ;-)

Comment: Just a note, setting a button to hidden disables user interaction on it. I'm not 100% sure, but I think setting the alpha to 0.0 has a similar effect. Instead, change the button's color/background to match the background which will be a similar visual effect, but not disable the button.

Comment: You are right. Setting object to hidden also disabled user interaction. But I am not sure if the same goes for alpha = 0.0...